# complexity to add two maps in Scala

Tags: scala, time-complexity, scala-collections

what is the complexity for the following statement:

```
val map4: Map[String, String] = map1 ++ map2
```

Is it `O(m+n)`, where `m` is the size of `map1` and `n` is the size of `map2` when map is immutable?

Is it `O(n)` when map is mutable?

If I am right, in this case, is immutable map still preferred?

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of Map.

In [performance-characteristics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) you find:

[image]

Comment: it's N * complexity(`++`)

Comment: for immutable and mutable, the complexity is the same?

Comment: only for HashSet / HashMap